# SQLAlchemy map function output to model

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using

- Python 3.5
- Flask (0.12)
- SQLAlchemy (1.3.19) with postgres (12.9).

I have sql function with int array parameter

```
public.get_something(array[1,2,3,4,5])
```

which returns table with 15 fields.

Is there a way to create SQLAlchemy model to map that 15 fields and query data from function output. I want to make it as clean as possible, like standard table querying - `session.query(SomeModel).all()` ?

Comment: What does `from sqlalchemy import func; session.query(func.get_something([1, 2, 3])).all()` get you?

Comment: Also https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#table-values-table-and-column-valued-functions-row-and-tuple-objects